# Uniform convergence of exponential distribution function

Tags: uniform-convergence, exponential-distribution

Suppose I have $X_1, X_2,...$ are iid with $Exp(\lambda)$ with 
$$G_{\lambda}(x)=1-exp(-\lambda x), \ \ \ \ \ x>0$$
Set
$$G_n(x)=1-exp(-\hat{\lambda}_n x), \ \ \ \ \ x>0$$
with
$$\hat{\lambda}_n=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i} $$
I would like to show that
$$\sup_x |G_n(x)-G_{\lambda}(x)| \rightarrow 0 \ \ \ \ a.s$$

I have tried to use the mean value theorem, for example,
$$|G_n(x)-G_{\lambda}(x)| =  |exp(-\lambda x) - exp(\hat{\lambda}_n x)| \\
= |xexp(-\lambda'x)| |\hat{\lambda}_n - \lambda| \\
<x|\hat{\lambda}_n - \lambda|
$$

I am not sure whether this is the correct move and hope someone would give me some suggestions.

Comment: $x\exp(-\lambda' x)$ is uniformly bounded in $x$ and for $\lambda'$ near $\lambda$. However $x$ is obviously not uniformly bounded on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: It happens that for every positive $a$, $b$ and $x$, $$|e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}|\leqslant\left|1-\frac{a}b\right|$$ thus, $$\sup_x\left|G_n(x)-G_\lambda(x)\right|\leqslant E\left|1-\frac{\lambda}{\hat\lambda_n}\right|$$ Can you conclude?